# Prepaid travel credit cards: Is there a low-cost card supporting top-up in multiple currencies, without conversion fees?

Tags: credit-card, foreign-exchange, eur-euro, usd-us-dollar, gbp-british-pound

With reference to the CantonFX cards http://www.caxtonfxcard.com/cards_description.asp

Which card do I use if I need to use multiple currencies at the lowest cost & I only want to carry one card? Do you need to choose the currency you want when you top up for the Euro card and the Global card or can you just top up in GBP/EUR/CHF and can pay multiple currencies - or is the Global card & USD especially required for this function? I would certainly like to avoid the 2.5% charge where possible.

I need to be able to transact in CHF, USD, GBP and EUR.

Feel free to recommend better alternative cards as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no card that will allow you to load and pay in multiple currencies.

For the Global Card, the amount remains in GBP and all the transactions will be marked-up for the exchange rate.

The USD card when you are funding from GBP, will also involve a conversion and a mark-up on the GDP/USD rate. The only difference is you are aware of the rate. The same applies to EUR card.

So essentially the question is when will the conversion happen, and do you know the rates up front or later after the statement is generated? The fees would more or less be same.

Plus on a prepaid card you money is locked upfront. It better to try and use your regular credit card and check out the rate being applied vs the rate offered at the time of loading a USD debit card.

Apart from credit you may also get loyalty points that may not be applicable on the debit card.